# Vandermonde's identity and the close form of $\sum_{k=0}^r C(n,k) C(m,r-k) x^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, probability-distributions, closed-form

I have a question related to Vandermonde's identity:

From Vandermonde's identity, we have:
$$
\binom{n+m}{r}=\sum_{k=0}^r \binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{r-k}
$$
Now, I have an extra term $x^k$ inside the sum, i.e.
$$
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^r \binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{r-k}x^k
$$

Is there any closed form solution available for $f(x)$? I would be grateful for any hint?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you need a closed form? To me, that seems like a pretty nice form already.

Comment: @user159517   Good comment! :-) It is part of bigger expression which needs further simplifications. BTW, with the same logic, Vandermonde's identity will be useless :-)

Comment: It's just because when analysing or dealing with functions, a representation as a polynomial with an explicit formula for the coefficients pretty much seems as nice as it gets.

Comment: @user159517 Agree but I am wondering if it has a simpler closed form, e.g. (1+x)^n can be written as binomial form but the first one is easier to work with and numerically compute...

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* A closed form is presumably not available. But, we can write it as the coefficient of a polynomial, which might be useful. Note, that $f(x)$ is dependent on $r$ and should be parametrized with it.

> The following holds
>
> \begin{align*}
> (1+xy)^n(1+y)^m&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(xy)^k\sum_{l=0}^m\binom{m}{l}y^l\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{{k+l=r}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{l}(xy)^ky^l\right)\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^{r}\binom{n}{k}\binom{m}{r-l}x^k\right)y^r\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}f(x;r)y^r
> \end{align*}
>
> If we denote with $[x^r]$ the coefficient of $x^r$ in a series, we can write according to (1) for $r\geq 0$
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(x;r)=[y^r](1+xy)^n(1+y)^m\qquad\qquad m,n\geq 0
> \end{align*}